# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec + Ant don't work

Tags: java, ant, command

I have found very stange bug.

I have a code:

```
private static void run(String command)
    {
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And I run the next line to compile an app automatically

```
run("C:\\Ant\\bin\\ant.bat -f " + projectPath + " release");
```

When it compiles the first time, everything is fine, but when I do it one more time, ant freezes and proc.waitFor() never finishes. Also, after compiling, I clean directory via ant

```
run("C:\\Ant\\bin\\ant.bat clean -f " + projectPath);
```

Firstly I was thinking that I have made a mistake somewhere, but no. After changing run():

```
private static void run(String command)
    {
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            String tmp;
            while((tmp = r.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //System.out.println("> " + tmp);
            }
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

it works! So, when logging is disabled, nothing works and verse, when it enabled, app works correctly and ant finishes. Does someone why it happens and how it may be fixed?

Comment: First things first: don't use `Runtime.exec()`; use a `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Comment: You need to be careful executing batch from Java.  It is best to invoke `cmd.exe` and provide it the batch file you want to process: `cmd /c batchfile`.  Note, in a project I work on, I invoke Ant using the java executable and `ant-launcher.jar`, bypassing the ant script stuff which has platform dependencies.  The main class for the ant launcher is `org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher`.  Have a look at the [Ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#viajava) on how to construct the command for invoking Ant.